# C# - Wix Toolset v3 missing: "Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.AssemblyDefaultWixExtensionAttribute"

Tags: c#, wix

Using Wix v3.11.

I have a C# solution with 3 projects in it:

1. eContactDeveloper: - Class library, the installer needs to place this dll in the user's C:\Program Files (x86)\eContact folder
2. eContactNetload.dll - Class library, the installer needs to RUN this CustomAction during install.
3. eContactInstaller: Wix Toolset v3.11 Installer project

eContactInstaller is referencing both projects. I am able to get the installer to create the folder and place the eContactDeveloper.dll file in the folder. I'm having a hard time getting the CustomAction to run.

Visual Studio is giving me this error:

> Either
> 'Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.AssemblyDefaultWixExtensionAttribute'
> was not defined in the assembly or the type defined in extension
> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset
> v3.11\bin\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll' could not be
> loaded.   eContactInstaller   candle.exe  0

The dll is clearly located in that folder. I've checked far too many times. I dont know what to do with this AssemblyDefaultWixExtensionAttribute

***Can anyone please help me figure out how to solve this issue?***

This is the primary CustomAction function inside **eContactNetload** that needs to run during the installation.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;


        /// <summary>
        ///     Every time an AutoCAD document is opened, the system automatically runs the acad20XXdoc.lsp file.
        ///     So we will append a command to NETLOAD the dll so that eContact will always be available to the user whenever they need it.
        /// </summary>
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult CustomAction()
        {
            // Get the current AutoCAD version that is installed on user's machine.
            string version = GetAutoCADVersion();

            // Locate the acad20XXdoc.lsp file.
            FileInfo lispFile = FindLispFile(version);

            // Set the line for the command to netload the dll into AutoCAD everytime an autocad document is opened.
            string lineText = @"(command ""_netload"" ""C:\\Program Files (x86)\\eContact\\eContactDeveloper.dll"")";

            // Check if the file exists.
            if (lispFile.Exists)
            {
                // Check if the command line (in lineText) already exists in the file.
                if (File.ReadLines(lispFile.FullName).Any(line => line.Trim() == lineText.Trim()))
                {
                    return ActionResult.Success;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Create the file if it doesn't exist.
                // lispFile.Create().Close();
            }
            try
            {
                // Add the command line to the file.
                using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(lispFile.FullName))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(lineText);
                }
                return ActionResult.Success;
            }
            catch
            {
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }
        }
```

My **Product.wxs**:

*NOTE:  GUIDs are purposefully masked with *******

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="******" Name="eContactCAD" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0" Manufacturer="test" UpgradeCode="******">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of eContactInstaller is already installed." />
        <Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="logo.ico" />
        <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="license.rtf" />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="eContactCAD" />
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
                <Directory Id="eContactFolder" Name="eContactCAD" />
            </Directory>
            <Component Id="RemoveAppDataFolder" Guid="******">
                <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveAppDataFolder" On="uninstall" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" Guid="******">
                <File Id="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" Name="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" Source="Dependencies\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="eContactInstaller" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="UserDataComponents" />
            <ComponentRef Id="RemoveAppDataFolder" />
        </Feature>
        <Binary Id="eContactNetloadBinary" SourceFile="$(var.eContactNetload.TargetDir)\eContactNetload.dll" />

        <CustomAction Id="Netload" BinaryKey="eContactNetloadBinary" DllEntry="Netload" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="Netload" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
        <UI>
            <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
        </UI>
    </Product>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="eContactDeveloper.dll" Guid="******">
                <File Id="eContactDeveloper.dll" Name="eContactDeveloper.dll" Source="$(var.eContactDeveloper.TargetDir)\eContactDeveloper.dll" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
        <ComponentGroup Id="UserDataComponents" Directory="eContactFolder">
            <Component Id="UserData" Guid="******">
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Test\eContactCAD" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
                <CreateFolder />
                <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveUserDataFolder" On="uninstall" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

My **CustomActions.wxs**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <CustomAction Id="LoadDLL" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]eContactNetload.dll&quot; /register" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" />
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="LoadDLL" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure to use the C# custom action project template that wix provides. It calls a postbuild target that calls MakeSfxCa that will out put yourassembly.dll and yourassembly.ca.dll.   The first is managed code, the second is wrapped with native code and it's this file that goes into your installer.

Second, you don't use an EXE CA to call your .ca.dll.  You use the Binary table to import the file into a row and then use a Dll Custom Action referencing the PK of the binary table and the name of your custom action.  The .ca.dll will have an exported function that fires up a middleware that hosts the CLR and calls your static method passing a Sesssion object which is marshaled to the msi handle running in native code provided by DTF.